# Generating random correlated x and y points using Numpy

Tags: python, random, numpy, correlation, normal-distribution

I'd like to generate correlated arrays of x and y coordinates, in order to test various matplotlib plotting approaches, but I'm failing somewhere, because I can't get `numpy.random.multivariate_normal` to give me the samples I want. Ideally, I want my x values between -0.51, and 51.2, and my y values between 0.33 and 51.6 (though I suppose equal ranges would be OK, since I can constrain the plot afterwards), but I'm not sure what mean (0, 0?) and covariance values I should be using to get these samples from the function.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As the name implies `numpy.random.multivariate_normal` generates normal distributions, this means that there is a non-null probability of finding points outside of any given interval. You can generate correlated uniform distributions but this a little more convoluted. Take a look [here](http://www.acooke.org/random.pdf) for two possible methods.

If you want to go with the normal distribution you can set up the sigmas so that your half-interval correspond to 3 standard deviations (you can also filter out the bad points if needed). In this way you will have ~99% of your points inside your interval, ex:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import scatter

xx = np.array([-0.51, 51.2])
yy = np.array([0.33, 51.6])
means = [xx.mean(), yy.mean()]  
stds = [xx.std() / 3, yy.std() / 3]
corr = 0.8         # correlation
covs = [[stds[0]**2          , stds[0]*stds[1]*corr], 
        [stds[0]*stds[1]*corr,           stds[1]**2]] 

m = np.random.multivariate_normal(means, covs, 1000).T
scatter(m[0], m[1])
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to implement a variation in order to create a correlated variable (i.e. numpy array) from an existing numpy array which has its own average and stdev?

Comment: Not sure if it's my mistake, but I had to do m[:,0] and m[:,1] for the scatterplot to render correctly.

Comment: @KetilMalde: You likely forgot the `.T` after the function call. `multivariate_normal` generates an array with a row per observation (1000 rows), and a column per variable (2 columns). `.T` transposes the array and the shape becomes `(2, 1000)`.

Answer (score 1):

can use Cholesky-decomposition to simulate correlated random variables given a correlation matrix - like [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/450769/347139)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# desired correlation matrix
cor_matrix = np.array([[1.0, 0.8],
                       [0.8, 1.0]])

L = np.linalg.cholesky(cor_matrix)

# build some signals that will result in the desired correlation matrix
X = L.dot(np.random.normal(0,1,(2,1000))) # the more the sample (1000) the better

# estimate their correlation matrix
print(np.corrcoef(X))
print(X.shape)
plt.scatter(X[0], X[1])
plt.show()
```

[image]