# Localized random points using numpy and pandas

Tags: python, random, numpy, matplotlib, pandas

My idea is to try and generate random data points (2D, x and y coordinates) that would lie in close proximity to one another mimicking the following scenario:

1. I choose e.g. 10 points on one object.
2. There are 200 such objects in a database.
3. I record the coordinates of 10 points on the same locations on all the objects. So the data I have consists of 200x10 rows, so that first 10 rows represent coordinates of 10 points sampled on the first object, the next 10 represent the same points on the second object, and so on.

Collections of points in objects should be close in the scatterplot, but they should not be exactly the same, or too far apart. Now if I use plain random generators, most of the time I end up with a lot of evenly spaced random points...

This is the procedure I`ve tried using numpy, pandas and matplotlib and a cool usage of multvariate normal from from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683821/generating-random-correlated-x-and-y-points-using-numpy) post.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import brewer2mpl as bmpl

#the part of the code I use for generating correlated ranges for points
#but I have used it for generating x,y coords as well but it didn`t work out 

corr = 0.95 
means = [200, 180]
stds = [10, 10]
covs = [[stds[0]**2, stds[0]*stds[1]*corr],[stds[0]*stds[1]*corr, stds[1]**2]]
coordstest = np.random.multivariate_normal(means, covs, 20)

#now the part for generating x and y coords

coords1x = np.random.uniform(coordstest[0,0], coordstest[0,1], 200)
coords1y = np.random.uniform(coordstest[1,0], coordstest[1,1], 200)
coords2x = np.random.uniform(coordstest[2,0], coordstest[2,1], 200)
coords2y = np.random.uniform(coordstest[3,0], coordstest[3,1], 200)
... up to 10

#them make them into two-column arrays

coords1 = np.vstack((coords1x, coords1y)).T
coords2 = np.vstack((coords2x, coords2y)).T
... up to 10

#and generate individual levels

individuals = np.arange(0,200) #generate individual levels
individuals = np.tile(individuals, 10)
individuals = pd.Series(individuals)

#finally generate pandas data frame and plot the results

allCoords = np.concatenate((coords1, coords2, coords3, coords4, coords5, coords6, coords7, coords8, coords9, coords10))
allCoords = pd.DataFrame(allCoords)
allCoords.columns = ['x','y']
allCoords['individuals'] = individuals
allCoords['index'] = allCoords.index.tolist()

allCoords = allCoords.sort_index(by=['individuals', 'index'])
del allCoords['index']
allCoords = allCoords.set_index(np.arange(0,2000))

plt.scatter(allCoords['x'], allCoords['y'], c = allCoords['individuals'], s = 40, cmap = 'hot')
```

This is the scatter

[image: Scatter plot]

and the same colored points should be grouped locally. Any ideas how this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact you generate normally distributed intervals, and then uniformly distributed points within. Not surprisingly, you end up with non colocated groups of points.

To get colocated groups of points, you should choose expected locations:

```
coordstest = np.vstack([np.random.uniform(150, 220, 20), 
                        np.random.uniform(150, 220, 20)]).T
```

Then generate points according to them:

```
coords = np.vstack([np.random.multivariate_normal(coordstest[i,:], covs, 200) 
                         for i in range(10)])
```

And plot

```
individuals = (np.arange(0,200).reshape(-1,1)*np.ones(10).reshape(1,-1)).flatten()
individuals = pd.Series(individuals)

allCoords = pd.DataFrame(coords, columns = ['x','y'])

plt.scatter(allCoords['x'], allCoords['y'], c = individuals, 
      s = 40, cmap = 'hot')
```

[image]

Note that point are generated with linear dependency due to nontrivial covariance paramether for multivariate_normal. If you don't need it, you can for example do

```
coords = np.vstack([np.random.multivariate_normal(coordstest[i,:], 
               [[10,0],[0,10]], 200) for i in range(10)])
```

resulting in

[image]

Comment: Thanks alko, this is really close to what I was trying to achieve, but my aim was to generete points that would be more localized, not forming perfect linear correlation between objects; they shoud be more similar to these examples [here](http://goo.gl/GYrqeT) and [here](http://goo.gl/yvWWCj).

Comment: @IanStuart that linear relation is due to `covs` paramether I took from your code, as a wild guess of your needs. You can simply use `np.random.normal` instead.